# ios push notification not working with urban airship

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, urbanairship.com

I am trying to add push notification in my iOS PhoneGap app. I am using Command Line Interface (CLI) to create PhoneGap app and add urban airship plugin. I am taking help from this link `https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push`. I changed `config.xml` from this location `project folder/platforms/ios/Project_name/config.xml`

below is my log

```
2014-03-31 14:03:12.435 ListCreator[3129:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-03-31 14:03:12.481 ListCreator[3129:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-03-31 14:03:12.605 ListCreator[3129:60b] [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 157] Production App Key is not valid.
2014-03-31 14:03:12.607 ListCreator[3129:60b] [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 161] Production App Secret is not valid.
2014-03-31 14:03:12.609 ListCreator[3129:60b] [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 145] App Key: xxxxxxxxREqtRFvTKQrQIQ
2014-03-31 14:03:12.611 ListCreator[3129:60b] [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 146] App Secret: xxxxxxxqg3C8DCEiWvA
2014-03-31 14:03:12.613 ListCreator[3129:60b] [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 147] Server: https://device-api.urbanairship.com
2014-03-31 14:03:12.617 ListCreator[3129:60b] [D] -[UAirship configureUserAgent] [Line 311] Setting User-Agent for UA requests to ListCreator 1.0 (iPod touch; iPhone OS 7.1; UALib 3.0.3; gDcwCI_1REqtRFvTKQrQIQ; en_US)
2014-03-31 14:03:12.627 ListCreator[3129:60b] [D] void PrintReachabilityFlags(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, const char *) [Line 79] Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
2014-03-31 14:03:12.635 ListCreator[3129:60b] [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 190] Registering UAURLProtocol
2014-03-31 14:03:12.649 ListCreator[3129:60b] [D] -[UALocationService startReportingSignificantLocationChanges] [Line 311] Attempt to start significant change service
2014-03-31 14:03:12.676 ListCreator[3129:60b] [D] -[UALocationService startReportingLocationWithProvider:] [Line 480] Location service not authorized or not enabled
2014-03-31 14:03:12.678 ListCreator[3129:60b] [CDVTimer][pushnotificationplugin] 80.036998ms
2014-03-31 14:03:12.681 ListCreator[3129:60b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 82.762003ms
2014-03-31 14:03:13.416 ListCreator[3129:60b] [D] -[UAStandardLocationProvider locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:] [Line 54] Standard location authorization changed 0
2014-03-31 14:03:13.417 ListCreator[3129:60b] [D] -[UALocationService locationProvider:withLocationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:] [Line 224] Location service did change authorization status 0
2014-03-31 14:03:13.419 ListCreator[3129:60b] [D] -[UASignificantChangeProvider locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:] [Line 51] Significant change did change authorization status 0
2014-03-31 14:03:13.421 ListCreator[3129:60b] [D] -[UALocationService locationProvider:withLocationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:] [Line 224] Location service did change authorization status 0
2014-03-31 14:03:14.456 ListCreator[3129:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-03-31 14:03:15.043 ListCreator[3129:60b] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/1CF70A66-2E2E-41DB-8357-F650DA7B6615/ListCreator.app/www/index.html
2014-03-31 14:03:15.482 ListCreator[3129:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '158.023926' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-03-31 14:03:27.645 ListCreator[3129:1403] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] [Line 238] Retrieved device id info from keychain.
2014-03-31 14:03:27.646 ListCreator[3129:1403] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] [Line 245] Loaded Device ID: C62AC604-20BA-44C7-BB6D-00E593B491E0
2014-03-31 14:03:27.648 ListCreator[3129:1403] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] [Line 246] Loaded Model Name: iPod5,1
2014-03-31 14:03:28.513 ListCreator[3129:60b] [D] __39-[UAAnalytics sendOperationWithEvents:]_block_invoke [Line 622] Analytics data sent successfully. Status: 200
```

In urban airship website i can see that total app open are `5`. Here is screen shot `http://nevadasoftbd.com/urban-airship.png`.

No push can sent and can't login into app also.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to verify your `Production App Key` and your `Production App Secret`

```
2014-03-31 14:03:12.605 ListCreator[3129:60b] [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 157] Production App Key is not valid.
2014-03-31 14:03:12.607 ListCreator[3129:60b] [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 161] Production App Secret is not valid.
```

Also you need to verify you are looking at the correct 'App' in Urban Airship, either the Production app or the Developer app.